# How to clear TextInput correctly?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, textinput

i'm creating an interface for a chat and I have a problem to clear correctly the field of a textInput.

Here is the code I have for the moment

```
export default class Chat extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            text: '',
            disabled: true,
            messages: [
                {
                    id:'1',
                    text:  'Hello',
                    avatar: 'http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/47/1480031586-1474755093-risitas721.png',
                    author: {
                        avatar: 'http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/47/1480031586-1474755093-risitas721.png',
                        username: 'Dr Risitas'
                    }
                },
                {
                    id:'2',
                    text:'How are you ?',
                    author : {
                        avatar: 'http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/47/1480031586-1474755093-risitas721.png',
                        username:'Dr Risitas'
                    }

                }
            ],
        }
    }

    //Checking input text before sending
    onTyping(text) {
        if(text && text.length >= 2) {
            this.setState({
                disabled: false,
                text
            })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                disabled: true
            })
        }
    }

    //Clear input text when send btn is pressed
    onSendBtnPressed = () => {
        this.textInput.clear();
        this.setState({disabled: true});
    }

    //Render each item of Flatlist
    renderChatItem = ({item}) => {
        //return <Text> {item.text}</Text>
        return <ChatItem message={item} />
    }
    //Key for data in FlatList component
    keyExtractor = (item, index) => index;

    render() {
        //extra style for sending button
        const extraBtnStyle = this.state.disabled ? styles.disabledBtn : styles.enabledBtn;
        //Different behavior to avoid the view when the keyboard is opened
        let behavior ='';
        if (Platform.OS == 'ios'){
            behavior = 'padding';
        }
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Header 
                centerComponent={{text: 'I Feel', style: { color: '#fff', fontSize: 20} }}
                containerStyles={{height: 56}} />
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.messages}
                    renderItem={this.renderChatItem}
                    keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                    inverted
                />
                <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={behavior}>
                    <View style={styles.inputBar}>

                        <TextInput style={styles.textBox} 
                            style={styles.textBox}
                            multiline
                            defaultHeight={30}
                            onChangeText={(text) => this.onTyping(text)}
                            ref = {(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
                        />

                        <TouchableHighlight 
                            style = {[styles.sendBtn, extraBtnStyle]}
                            disabled = {this.state.disabled}
                            onPress = {this.onSendBtnPressed}>

                            <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}> Send </Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView> 
            </View>
        );
    }    
}
```

The problem is that when the Send button is pressed, the text disappears well, but if I continue to write just after pressing the button, the old message concatenates with the new one I am writing. To avoid this I have to click on the Send button, then click on the text field and then I can write the new message without having any concatenation

it looks like we need to do a new focus on textinput, but I'm not sure how to do it.
I hope I've been clear, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.textInput.current.clear()`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers but I managed to solve the problem.

In reality it was not a problem with the code but it was caused by the Samsung keyboard by default. 
He kept the old message sent each time. So I solved the problem by using the Google keyboard.

So if someone has the same problem, just change the keyboard.